# restorecon and manage_accounts running continuously on Google Compute Engine Centos 6

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Any idea why 'restorecon ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' processes are being launched continuously on a GCE instance running CentOS 6? That (along with 'manage_accounts') is chewing up a lot of CPU time. The restorecon command is being run for the .ssh/authorized_keys file under several different home directories.

A couple of data points:

1. I'm unable to ssh into this GCE instance through the Google Cloud Console ('Open in Browser Window' option), but ssh from a regular shell using the appropriate private key (ssh -i  @) works fine.
2. The 'ls -Z ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' command (for displaying the SE Linux context) shows the following output:
   -rw-------.   system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0  authorized_keys
3. Rebooting the GCE instance did not fix the problem: The processes continue to be spawned every few seconds.

I'm perplexed. Any clues on what's spawning these processes?

Comment: what's your auth.log look like? is port 22 open to `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: some program may be continuously modifying permissions on `authorized_keys`, and restorecon is constantly running to fix them.

Comment: Port 22 is open only to a small set of IP addresses, so I'm not suspecting unwanted ssh attempts. 'ls -l' on authorized_keys always shows '600 (rw only for user)', unlikely the permissions are being changed by some process. The 'manage_accounts' process is also invoked continuously which I suspect may be triggering the 'restorecon' process. Have no idea why.

Comment: I find it unusual that “ls -l”  always shows 600 , I understand that this may lead you to believe that the permissions aren't being changed. Maybe take a moment and look at the programs you are running just in case.

Comment: running `ls -l` and looking at the result with your human eyeballs is a very crude way to determine whether the permissions are *always* 600. if there's a program changing it, and then restorecon quickly changes it back, you may never see it change.

Comment: restorecon's entire purpose in life is to correct illegal/incorrect permissions on files that it watches. something on the machine is trying to change permissions of your SSH keys. that's a very worrisome sign, and I recommend that you run a complete security audit of your machine.

Comment: Ok, so I wrote some C code to continuously monitor the permissions of the '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' file using the fstat() call. The program checks the permissions 500 times a second. The st_mode field of the stat struct returned by that call always shows 0x8180, what I would expect. No changes to permissions as far as I can tell at least over a period of several minutes, while restorecon gets invoked every few seconds

Comment: Another data point (not entirely sure if this is the cause or the result): while the permissions are not changed, the selinux context of the file indeed appears to be changing because of invocation of  'restorecon' by  /usr/bin/python /usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_accounts.py. Notice the invocation of the 'restorecon' command in accounts.py file in the google_daemon directory. Why is 'manage_accounts.py' being invoked periodically by a daemon of the same name (manage_accounts.py) as seen by the following process entries (see next comment):

Comment: root      1315     1  0 Nov19 ?        00:09:21 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_accounts.py

root     29657  1315  0 17:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_accounts.py

The pid 1315 is always up, but the child 29657 is temporary and repeatedly spawned. I suspect the child is invoking 'restorecon' repeatedly (see accounts.py).

Comment: Formatting of the previous comment is messed up. I'm trying to show two different process entries for pid 1315 (parent) and 29657 (child).